# How to add user attributes to Keycloak token

Tags: java, postgresql, token, keycloak

Keycloak is associated with PostgreSQL. The keycloak.user_attribute table stores Keycloak user attributes. When adding an attribute to a specific user in the keycloak.user_attribute table in PosgreSQL, it does not appear in Keycloak. Tell me how to fix it. I'm user Keycloak 3.4.0

[Add attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpeZi.jpg)

[Does not appear in Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRNaa.jpg)

Comment: I had to restart keycloak to see the attribute inserted

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: which keycloak version are you using?

Comment: I'm using keycloak version 3.4.0 and have access to the keycloak Admin Console